# Where are the images in a TImageCollection held Delphi

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

Is it possible to access the images in TImageCollection from the executable or the resource file. i.e. outside the IDE.  How are these images held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, image list and image collection images are stored in the DFM files. You can see this if you go to the form or data module containing the image list or collection, and then press Alt+F12 to see the DFM code. Alternatively, you can simply open the DFM file in your favourite text editor.

And these DFMs are embedded into your EXE as RCDATA resources, so you can see them if you open your EXE in a resource editor.

Comment: That has saved me with a lot of hassle, I had an image collection which when I was adding images to it 2 blank entries were inserted.  This crashes the Image Collection Editor making it impossible to add images.  I was able to dive into the DFM, find t he blank entries and delete them and the image collection editor is now working fine.  Thanks for the pointer and no thanks to Embarcadero for not handling black entries.'

Comment: @JohnBarrat: I'm glad you have resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, your EXE can access the images via the `TImageCollection.Images` property, which is a collection of `TImageCollectionItem` objects.

`TImageCollectionItem` has a `SourceImages` property, which is a collection of `TImageCollectionSourceItem` objects.

`TImageCollectionSourceItem` has an `Image` property of type `TWICImage`